# Dash in Schema Name - Groovy SQL query error

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, groovy

A Quick groovy syntax question here:

I'm working with Groovy SQL capabilities (Groovy 2.4)

My Schema contains dashes, like `"SAMPLE-SCHEMA"` and my table is called `"SAMPLE_TABLE"`

When I run the following I'm getting an exception that the relation does not exist.
I'm running against Postgres 9.6 with the correct driver.

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance(...)
sql.eachRow('SELECT SAMPLE_COLUMN FROM \"SAMPLE-SCHEMA\".SAMPLE_TABLE') { 
  row -> // do something with row here
}
```

If I query another schema without Dashes it works flowlessly.

The exception message is:

```
Caught: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "SAMPLE-SCHEMA.SAMPLE_TABLE" does not exist
```

How can I adjust my query to make it work? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer, the schema in postgresql is case sensitive, so I by mistake called "SAMPLE-SCHEMA" and it should have been "sample-schema" instead.

I'm not deleting the question because it might help someone